# How to exclude node_modules from create-react-app testing?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, create-react-app, package.json

I want to make tests of my create-react-app using jest.

One of node_modules have test-error,

[image]

but I don't want jest to work with node_modules folder.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#configuration) I found configuration property "collectCoverageFrom" and tried to use itin my package.json:

```
  ....
  "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom ",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "jest": {
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "!/node_modules/*"
         ]
  }
```

But there is nothing changed.

Comment: [testpathignorepatterns](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testpathignorepatterns-array-string).

Comment: @Andy 
Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest options:

  • collectCoverageFrom
  • coverageReporters
  • coverageThreshold
  • snapshotSerializers.

Comment: Then I'm surprised it's _not_ ignoring your `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Oh, it is ignoring your modules folder, but your test relies on something that's not working properly. That's a different problem.

Comment: It works by node_module and I don't want jest to analyse it(

Comment: Because it's looking for `window` [you might have to mock it.](https://blog.cloudboost.io/how-to-mock-es6-modules-and-globals-with-jest-814de9b24c6d)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing with coverage.

One of your components is using `react-mic` package provides access to audio through `window.AudioContext`.

You have different ways to solve it.

1. You may mock `window.AudioContext`. It would be really hard to achieve. I don't really suggest you doing that.
2. You can [mock `react-mic` module](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules). That's much more achievable than #1 but still quite hard.
3. You can rely on `shallow()` in your tests. So your will never need to mock anything related to Audio at all. I'd like to suggest you doing that way.

Comment: So weird, In my case I tested a simple typescript function from a file, jest showed me an error  ```Jest encountered an unexpected token```, but when i deleted an api function which related with ```axios```  and tested again. it works like calm.

Answer (score 0):

It's like that already. Jest ignores `node_modules`. What you see is just a stack trace. Double check your tests code, something wrong is happening there.

Answer (score -3):

Try using [`testPathIgnorePatterns`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testpathignorepatterns-array-string) when configuring jest:

```
"jest": {
    ...
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/(build|docs|node_modules)/"
    ]
```

Comment: Krif Create React App only supports overriding these Jest options: • collectCoverageFrom • coverageReporters • coverageThreshold • snapshotSerializers.

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't see any reason why Create React App would be limited to these options.

Comment: There is details: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#configuration

Comment: Yes `create-react-app` limits us of using this option